# Overriding lib.es5.d.ts type definitions

Tags: typescript

`lib.es5.d.ts` defines

```js
interface TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> {
    enumerable?: boolean;
    configurable?: boolean;
    writable?: boolean;
    value?: T;
    get?: () => T;
    set?: (value: T) => void;
}
```

However, a more accurate definition would be:

```js
type TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> = {
    enumerable?: boolean;
    configurable?: boolean;
} & ({
    set?: (value: T) => void;
} | {
    get?: () => T;
} | {
    writable?: boolean;
    value?: T;
})
```

How can one replace `lib.es5.d.ts` definition with the more accurate one?

Using `interface` extends the original definition - making all of the enhancements pointless.

Comment: How would you expect the behavior of the original and your improved version to differ?

Comment: @Craig Hicks - one can't do stupid things like set `writable: true` for a getter or a setter - which errors at run time.

Comment: You can't override interfaces or delete lib, make your own type with same or different name and import it